# Bootstrap 3 Carousel with thumbnails

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I need to create a responsive carousel with thumbnails same as below URL. I saw few questions for the same but none of them helped.

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/connected-carousels/

Please let me know if anyone has already implemented it?

I found the solution in the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471019/bootstrap-carousel-with-thumbnails but it shows all the thumbnails together and if the number of images are many then the size will be small.

Thanks

Comment: You could make the thumbnails smaller like this: http://bootply.com/108490

Comment: What if i have 20 images? i need the thumbnails to slide once reach the last visible item and at a time 4/5 images should be visible.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I have the same issue, number of images vary and they should displayed in one rows as with scrolling